# Auto updating a form after user inputs different value for a quantity field?

Tags: forms

I wonder if anyone can help me please. I am looking for some code that automatically updates a quantity field after user inputs any number. I can achieve this with a "Change" button but I dont want that. It looks ugly. :)  Thanks in advance.

```
<input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1"/>
<input name="adjustButton' . $item_id .'" type="submit" value="Change"/>
<input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add even handlers to the keyup action of the input boxes that run your calculation
http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

assuming jquery is installed

```
   $("#myInputBox").keyup(function() {
        $("quanity").value = this.value;
   });
```

you may want to change $("#quanity").value = (function() { Add up the total }